# Google MarkerClusterer does not show the markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am trying to replace my data with the ones provided by [this sample code](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html), but my code does not work. I just added an array called results and tried to pass its lat and lan values to the map but for some reasons it does not work.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MarkerClusterer v3 Simple Example</title>
    <style >
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      #map-container {
        padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
        width: 600px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer';
      if (document.location.search.indexOf('compiled') !== -1) {
        script += '_compiled';
      }
      script += '.js"><' + '/script>';
      document.write(script);
    </script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {

        var results = [
          [
            'Alexs loc', '37.9908372',
            '23.7383394', '0',
            'id-90'], [
              'John Jamess loc', '37.9908372',
              '23.7383394', '1',
              'id-89'], [
                'Normans loc', '38.075352',
                '23.807885', '3',
                'id-12'],  [
                  'Jack Moores loc', '37.9908372',
                  '23.7383394', '2',
                  'id-67'],  ];
          var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9908372, 23.7383394);

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

          var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[i][1], results[i][2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <a href="?compiled">Compiled</a> |
      <a href="?">Standard</a> version of the script.
    </p>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not checked but I see the code where you are creating marker in loop. Here position should refer to placeLoc and not latLng

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: placeLoc
          });
```